# Condition Numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra, condition-number

I'm working my way through a basic textbook on Numerical Linear Algebra, and one of the problems asks if the fact that an arbitrary invertible matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ is perfectly conditioned in the 1-norm implies that it is perfectly conditioned in the $\infty$-norm. Formally:

cond$_{1}(A) = 1 \Longrightarrow \text{cond}_{\infty}(A) = 1$ ?

I can prove that this holds for symmetric matrices (i.e when $A = A^{T}$), but not for the general case. My intuition was to try to disprove this by contradiction, but I cannot think of/compute any non-symmetric matrix $B$ such that $det(B) \neq 0$ *and* $\text{cond}_{1}(B) = 1$. I've also been trying to come up with something utilizing $\text{cond}_{1}(A^{T}A)$, $\text{cond}_{1}(AA^{T})$, or $\text{cond}_{1}(A^{T})$, but so far have only succeeded in showing that the lower bound $1 \leq \text{cond}_{\infty}(A)$.

If anyone could offer any help with finding a suitable counterexample or give a hint on how to approach this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$  B = \begin{pmatrix}0 & \sqrt{10} \\ -\sqrt{10} & 0 \end{pmatrix}  $$

- $B$ is antisymmetric.
- $\det(B) = 10$.
- $\kappa_1(B) = \sqrt{10} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} = 1$.

This is the example you requested.  It is not an example with $\kappa_\infty \neq 1$.

There is no example with $\kappa_\infty = 1$.

$||B||_1$ is the maximum absolute column sum of $B = \left( b_{ij} \right)_{i,j=1}^n$ and $||B||_\infty$ is the maximum absolute row sum of $B$.  Then \begin{align*}
||B||_1 &= \max_{1 \leq j \leq n} \sum_{i=1}^n|b_{ij}|  \\
||B||_\infty &= \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} \sum_{j=1}^n|b_{ij}|  \\
\end{align*}
Observe that $||B^{-1}||_1$ is the quotient of the maximum absolute row sum of $B$ and the determinant of $B$.  Observe that $||B^{-1}||_\infty$ is the quotient of the maximum absolute column sum of $B$ and the determinant of $B$.
\begin{align*}
||B^{-1}||_1 &= \frac{1}{\det B} \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} \sum_{j=1}^n|b_{ij}|  \\
||B^{-1}||_\infty &= \frac{1}{\det B} \max_{1 \leq j \leq n} \sum_{i=1}^n|b_{ij}|  \\
\end{align*}

Then
\begin{align*}
\kappa_1(B) &= ||B||_1 \, ||B^{-1}||_1  \\
    &= \max_{1 \leq j \leq n} \sum_{i=1}^n|b_{ij}| \cdot \frac{1}{\det B} \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} \sum_{j=1}^n|b_{ij}|  \\
    &= \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} \sum_{j=1}^n|b_{ij}| \cdot \frac{1}{\det B} \max_{1 \leq j \leq n} \sum_{i=1}^n|b_{ij}|  \\
    &= ||B||_\infty \, ||B^{-1}||_\infty  \\
    &= \kappa_\infty(B)  \text{.}
\end{align*}

(Since you only ask for a hint, I won't explain why the formulas for the norms of the inverse matrices are correct.)

Comment: I checked this with Python, and got that ```cond(A,1) = 5```, not 1.

Comment: @victor__von__doom : Did you include the $1/5$ in front?

Comment: Yeah, this is what I ran: A = 1/5 * np.array([[2,1], [3,0]], dtype=float);     print(A,cond(A,1))  --- it outputted 5 for me. Lmk if I'm just doing something dumb

Comment: Actually it's even easier to see by hand: $A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 5/3 \\ 5 & -10/3 \end{bmatrix}$, which has a 1 norm of 5 from the first column.

Comment: @victor__von__doom : When I `print A` using your code, I get the zero matrix..., so I'm skeptical as to its correctness.  Further, there is no way the $1$-norm of $\begin{pmatrix}0.4 & 0.2 \\ 0.6 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ is $5$.

Comment: I agree - $\|A\|_{1} = 1$. However, $\|A^{-1}\|_{1} = 5 \neq 1$, as shown above, and $\kappa_{1}(A) = \|A\|_{1} \|A^{-1}\|_{1} = 1 \times 5 = 5$

Comment: @victor__von__doom : You write "perfectly conditioned in the 1-norm implies that it is perfectly conditioned in the $\infty$-norm. Formally: $$\kappa_1(A) = 1 \implies \kappa)\infty(A) = 1$$".  That wording asserts $\kappa_1$ is the $1$-norm.  Did you intend it to be something that is not declared in the Question?

Comment: My bad - I thought $\kappa_{1}(A)$ was how you signified the *condition number* of $A$. My original textbook is not in English, so I assumed there was a different notation, and some other answers on StackExchange led me to believe that - my mistake. I'll update the question. Sorry again!

Comment: @victor__von__doom : No worries.  That's why we define our notation -- to avoid unexpected intepretations.

Comment: I just want to mention: on Mathworks (https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2017/07/17/what-is-the-condition-number-of-a-matrix/), they explicitly say  $\kappa(A)=\|A\|\|A^{-1}\|$

Comment: @victor__von__doom : Updated.

Comment: Thank you again, and sorry for the mixup. This site deserves more patient people like you.

Comment: @victor__von__doom : Made a tiny edit:  the leading $1/5$ was left over from the previous matrix.  Since a scalar multiple appears in the norm and its reciprocal appears in the norm of the inverse, the scalar multiple does not matter.  So I removed it.  Nothing else changes.